# url working in console but not in document

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I get the following code to make the url active in the document. When I console log the url, I can click on it and go the page. The url listed in the document is just text. (The app.js starts with the document ready function and the information is coming in correctly from the api).

```
   $.ajax({
         url: queryURL,
            method: "GET",
          }).done(function(response) {
     var events  = response.events;
     for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var tRow = $("<tr>");
          var url =  events[i].url 

          console.log(events[i].url);
          tRow.append($("<td>").text(events[i].name.text));  
          tRow.append($("<td>").html(url));
          tRow.append($("<td>").text(events[i].start.local));
          tRow.append($("<td>").text(events[i].end.local));

          $("#eventTable").append(tRow);
            }

            eventDB.push({
              event,
              address,
              distance,
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to append the url with anchor attribute to make it clickable.
example: `<a href="url">`

otherwise its a plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an a href="..." tag otherwise it's a plain text

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the guidance with the suggested answers. Both needed to be applied. I applied them and the resulting code works:

```
$.ajax({
        url: queryURL,
        method: "GET",
      }).done(function(response) {
var events  = response.events;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          var tRow = $("<tr>");
          var url =  events[i].url 

          console.log(events[i].url);
          tRow.append($("<td>").text(events[i].name.text));  
          tRow.append($("<td>").html("<a href=" + events[i].url + ">Link</a>"));
          tRow.append($("<td>").text(events[i].start.local));
          tRow.append($("<td>").text(events[i].end.local));

          $("#eventTable").append(tRow);
        }
```

Comment: please accept my answer if it works. "thanks" in stackoverflow is a vote and acceptance.